# RHPAM User Group management with LDAP

Tags: jboss, ldap, redhat, jbpm, rhpam

I am able to integrate the LDAP with Redhat PAM 7 version my authorization and authentication works fine with ldap but the admin console security page on business central still shows the groups and users from properties files only i saw the management properties of business central.

I assume this one use the user properties realm by default .If i want to show the ldap users/roles  under the admin console then what is the exact configuration needs to be done.